# Oracle 10g - convert columns to string

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with x columns and i need drop 4 of them, but before i need transform these columns into varchar in json format.

Example

how is now

```
car
-----------------------------
id    name   color  year  HP
--   ------  ------ ----  ---
1    porche  green  2014  350
```

the result i need after drop 3 columns and create detail column

```
car
--------------------------------------------------
id    name   detail
--   ------  -------------------------------------
1    porche  {color: 'green', year: 2014, HP: 350}
--------------------------------------------------
```

How can i achieve this in update script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a temporary table using concatenations and then renaming it:

```
create table your_table_new as
select 
    id, name, '{color: ''' || color || ''', year: ' || year || ', HP: ' || HP || '}' as detail
from your_table;


drop table your_table;
rename your_table_new to your_table;
```